# Is it a good idea to use emberjs only in some pages when using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have a rails app that has pretty standard things, except for two pages that require a lot of JS.

I was wondering if it's a good choice to use ember *just* for those two pages while keeping Rails standard for everything else? Or should I rewrite everything in emberjs + rails as API backend?

Comment: if you would otherwise duplicate alot of views for html/ember.js yes(this will save you time when you have to do maintenance), otherwise why bother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a case-by-case situation. Why do those two pages require a lot of JS? The answer is probably "because of an implementation decision you made." Adding Ember to the mix is probably going to prompt you to revisit a lot of implementation decisions to reconsider which tools are appropriate to use in which places.